# Sonar report Duplicate block even the 2 class is not related

Tags: java, duplicates, sonarqube, serializable

I have a abstract class something as follow:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditModel extends BaseModel implements IEditable {

    private Long createdBy;

    @CurrentUser(type = PersistenceType.CREATE)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    public Long getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
}
```

Sonar reported duplicate block for the `getCreatedBy()` and `setCreatedBy()` method. When I click for detail, it show me its duplicated by another class, which is `ReservedToken.java`.

The following is part of my ReservedToken.java code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ReservedTokens")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "reservedToken.updateHoldFromReleaseFlag", query = "UPDATE ReservedToken SET holdFromRelease = ? WHERE tokenSerialNo = ? and companyId = ? ") })
public class ReservedToken implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long createdBy;

    @CurrentUser(type = PersistenceType.CREATE)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    public Long getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
}
```

Both class no have any relationship, I am curious why it will still report duplicate in ReservedToken.java. Is it false positive? Or its because of `Serializable`? BaseModel is implements BaseModel as well.

Comment: They *are* duplicated, those lines are exactly the same. That's not necessarily bad, or wrong; SonarQube can't tell you that.

Comment: Is it means I am actually can mark as false positive? Since I am require all the class to use in different way.

Comment: I would mark it as `Won't Fix`. `False Positive` means that the rule works incorrectly. In your case the rule works correctly. It marked that two blocks are exactly the same. The rule doesn't understand that the context, so it cannot do anything more.